# Lightcase.js and dataTables.js Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, datatables

I'm using lightcase.js to load another page as an iframe on my page. Here I am also using dataTables.js to present data to my user so he can click on an eye icon at the end related to that record so he can view more information and lightcase open that page in the same page as an iframe.

Problem is, in the page 1 of my datable it works fine. But when it has more records and go to a page > 1, lightcase stops working so when user click on the eye icon page, browser will redirect to that page.

**Sample code:**

```
<script src="http://localhost/mysite/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/mysite/assets/js/lightcase.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Contact #</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      .....
      .....
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>0718064010</td>
      <td>2015-06-23 11:30:20</td>
      <td>takas</td>
      .....
      .....
      <td><a href="http://localhost/mysite/index.php/inquiry/view/9" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a[data-rel^=lightcase]').lightcase();
  });
</script>
```

Please help me with fixing this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you only attach a click handler to `<a>`-tags on visible rows, page #1. You must attach the handler each time dataTables is redrawn, i.e when the user clicks on another page. Replace the two document ready sections with :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
       $('a[data-rel^=lightcase]').lightcase();
   });
   $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. I'm new to JavaScript and events so your answer made me learn about them a lot.